# NSTextField doubleValue localization confusion

Tags: objective-c, localization

I am from germany. So I have a little problem with localization and the property *doubleValue* of the class *NSTextField*. Comma and points are different from the U.S.

```
double a = self.heightTextField.doubleValue;
```

If I have a "11,11" in my textfield I only get the integer part unless I write "11.11" with a point. So I guess I have to convert this value according to my current location. No big deal. NSNumberFormatter will do that.

But if I assign a value to the property it all works fine automatically. "11.11" gets converted into "11,11" on the NSTextField without me doing anything.

```
self.heightTextField.doubleValue = 11.11;
```

Why is that so?
Why is the the value from the controller converted automatically when send to the view but when I read a value from the view I have to convert it myself? Can I get automatic conversion both ways?

Comment: Are you willing to make use of NSNumberFormatter and the computer's "locale" setting?  That'll allow your app to do the right thing depending on what country they're sitting in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number handling in NSTextField is from the old, old days, and is being gently deprecated in favor of NSFormatters, so it’s not surprising it’s kind of spotty.

As @Michael says, if you want to handle different localizations of you should add an NSNumberFormatter to your field. You can just drag one off of the Interface Builder’s classes palette and onto the field in question.